# Cannot Create Tables in Postgres SQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I am trying to create tables in my postgres database using a .sql file and psql

Here is the command that I am using to load the file

`psql -U postgres -d dbname -a -f path\to\file\createPostgresSchema.sql`

After entering my password, I am met with the following error messages

```
psql:path\to\file\createPostgresSchema.sql:106: ERROR:  column "user_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist

CREATE TABLE plantdisease(
  plant_disease_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

  CONSTRAINT fk_plant
    FOREIGN KEY(plant_id)
      REFERENCES plant(plant_id),

  CONSTRAINT fk_disease
    FOREIGN KEY(disease_id)
      REFERENCES disease(disease_id)
);
psql:path\to\file\createPostgresSchema.sql:118: ERROR:  column "plant_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist

CREATE TABLE plantpest(
  plant_pest_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

  CONSTRAINT fk_plant
    FOREIGN KEY(plant_id)
      REFERENCES plant(plant_id),

  CONSTRAINT fk_pest
    FOREIGN KEY(pest_id)
      REFERENCES pest(pest_id)
);
psql:path\to\file\createPostgresSchema.sql:130: ERROR:  column "plant_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
CREATE TABLE garden(
  garden_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

  CONSTRAINT fk_user
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id)
      REFERENCES sproutshareuser(user_id),

  light_level varchar,

  CONSTRAINT fk_soil
    FOREIGN KEY(soil_id)
      REFERENCES soil(soil_id)
);
psql:path\to\file\createPostgresSchema.sql:143: ERROR:  column "user_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
```

Here is the .sql file

```
/* Remove Tables if they exist */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sproutshareuser;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS plant;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS userplant;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS plantdisease;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS plantpest;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS soil;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS disease;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pest;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS garden;


CREATE TYPE soil_type AS ENUM (
  'sandy',
  'silt',
  'clay',
  'loamy'
);

CREATE TYPE nutrient_level AS ENUM (
  'depleted',
  'deficient',
  'adequate',
  'sufficient',
  'surplus'
);

CREATE TYPE ph_level AS ENUM (
  'basic',
  'neutral',
  'Acidic'
);

CREATE TYPE threat_level AS ENUM (
  'No_Threat',
  'Partial_Threat',
  'Threatened'
);

CREATE TABLE sproutshareuser(
  user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name varchar,
  last_name varchar,
  email_address varchar,
  language varchar,
  zip_code int
);

CREATE TABLE plant(
  plant_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  common_name varchar,
  latin_name varchar,
  light_level varchar,
  min_temp int,
  max_temp int,
  rec_temp int,
  hardiness_zone varchar,
  soil_type soil_type,
  image varchar
);


CREATE TABLE soil(
  soil_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  soil_type soil_type,
  ph_level ph_level,
  nitrogen_level nutrient_level,
  phosp_level nutrient_level,
  potas_level nutrient_level
);

CREATE TABLE disease(
  disease_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  disease_name varchar,
  threat_level threat_level,
  care_tips varchar
);

CREATE TABLE pest(
  pest_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  pest_name varchar,
  threat_level threat_level,
  care_tips varchar
);
CREATE TABLE userplant(
  user_plant_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  
  CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES sproutshareuser(user_id),
  
  CONSTRAINT fk_plant FOREIGN KEY(plant_id) REFERENCES plant(plant_id),
  
  CONSTRAINT fk_garden FOREIGN KEY(garden_id) REFERENCES garden(garden_id),

  CONSTRAINT fk_disease
    FOREIGN KEY(plant_disease_id)
      REFERENCES plantdisease(plant_disease_id),
  
  CONSTRAINT fk_pest
    FOREIGN KEY(plant_pest_id)
      REFERENCES plantpest(plant_pest_id),

  plant_qty int,
  planting_date date,
  plant_difficulty int,
  plant_quality int
);

CREATE TABLE plantdisease(
  plant_disease_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  
  CONSTRAINT fk_plant
    FOREIGN KEY(plant_id)
      REFERENCES plant(plant_id),
  
  CONSTRAINT fk_disease
    FOREIGN KEY(disease_id)
      REFERENCES disease(disease_id)
);

CREATE TABLE plantpest(
  plant_pest_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

  CONSTRAINT fk_plant
    FOREIGN KEY(plant_id)
      REFERENCES plant(plant_id),

  CONSTRAINT fk_pest
    FOREIGN KEY(pest_id)
      REFERENCES pest(pest_id)
);
CREATE TABLE garden(
  garden_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

  CONSTRAINT fk_user
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id)
      REFERENCES sproutshareuser(user_id),
  
  light_level varchar,

  CONSTRAINT fk_soil
    FOREIGN KEY(soil_id)
      REFERENCES soil(soil_id)
);
```

Why can't the fields user_id and plant_id be referenced?  I tried moving those create table scripts to the top of the file but no success.

Comment: You have an issue on your sql file, here you are referencing a column from another table but you are not creating that column on the current table

Comment: 106: ERROR:  column "user_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist -
For the error above, the table sproutshareuser and column user_id is defined as SERIAL PRIMARY KEY.  I don't see why postgres cannot find that column in the table

Comment: the last create table statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues with your `.sql` file that's why it is not working while trying to create tables and their reference in PostgreSQL, Here is the full file with correction-

```
/* Remove Tables if they exist */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sproutshareuser;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS plant;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS userplant;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS plantdisease;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS plantpest;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS soil;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS disease;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pest;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS garden;


CREATE TYPE soil_type AS ENUM (
  'sandy',
  'silt',
  'clay',
  'loamy'
);

CREATE TYPE nutrient_level AS ENUM (
  'depleted',
  'deficient',
  'adequate',
  'sufficient',
  'surplus'
);

CREATE TYPE ph_level AS ENUM (
  'basic',
  'neutral',
  'Acidic'
);

CREATE TYPE threat_level AS ENUM (
  'No_Threat',
  'Partial_Threat',
  'Threatened'
);

CREATE TABLE sproutshareuser(
  user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name varchar,
  last_name varchar,
  email_address varchar,
  language varchar,
  zip_code int
);

CREATE TABLE plant(
  plant_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  common_name varchar,
  latin_name varchar,
  light_level varchar,
  min_temp int,
  max_temp int,
  rec_temp int,
  hardiness_zone varchar,
  soil_type soil_type,
  image varchar
);


CREATE TABLE soil(
  soil_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  soil_type soil_type,
  ph_level ph_level,
  nitrogen_level nutrient_level,
  phosp_level nutrient_level,
  potas_level nutrient_level
);

CREATE TABLE disease(
  disease_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  disease_name varchar,
  threat_level threat_level,
  care_tips varchar
);

CREATE TABLE plantdisease(
  plant_disease_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  plant_id int, 
  disease_id int,
  CONSTRAINT fk_plant
    FOREIGN KEY(plant_id)
      REFERENCES plant(plant_id),
  
  CONSTRAINT fk_disease
    FOREIGN KEY(disease_id)
      REFERENCES disease(disease_id)
);

CREATE TABLE pest(
  pest_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  pest_name varchar,
  threat_level threat_level,
  care_tips varchar
);

CREATE TABLE plantpest(
  plant_pest_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  plant_id int, 
  pest_id int,
  CONSTRAINT fk_plant
    FOREIGN KEY(plant_id)
      REFERENCES plant(plant_id),

  CONSTRAINT fk_pest
    FOREIGN KEY(pest_id)
      REFERENCES pest(pest_id)
);

CREATE TABLE garden(
  garden_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id int,
  soil_id int,
  light_level varchar,
  CONSTRAINT fk_user
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id)
      REFERENCES sproutshareuser(user_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_soil
    FOREIGN KEY(soil_id)
      REFERENCES soil(soil_id)
);

CREATE TABLE userplant(
  user_plant_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id int,
  plant_id int,
  garden_id int, 
  plant_disease_id int, 
  plant_pest_id int,
  plant_qty int,
  planting_date date,
  plant_difficulty int,
  plant_quality int,
  
  CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES sproutshareuser(user_id),
  
  CONSTRAINT fk_plant FOREIGN KEY(plant_id) REFERENCES plant(plant_id),
  
  CONSTRAINT fk_garden FOREIGN KEY(garden_id) REFERENCES garden(garden_id),

  CONSTRAINT fk_disease
    FOREIGN KEY(plant_disease_id)
      REFERENCES plantdisease(plant_disease_id),
  
  CONSTRAINT fk_pest
    FOREIGN KEY(plant_pest_id)
      REFERENCES plantpest(plant_pest_id)
);
```

**See Reference:**

1. https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-foreign-key/
2. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nFsD26ZBbTGp7DJRHrmvsD/0

Comment: I see where I went wrong!  Thank you very much.

Comment: i dont have the reputation unfortunately but the feedback was recorded